# Images 3D Monodroid

Tags: image, 3d, xamarin.android

I'm trying to include images with 3D effects. 
Is there any way to do using Monodroid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without having any idea what you are trying to do, all I can offer is one of the samples that applies 3d animations to images:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/ApiDemo/Animation

Comment: I would want to build a 3D image, and allow users to touch and drag the image in screen.